# How to decrypt a message(using php) encrypt by rails(aes gem)?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, aes

I encrypt some message using AES(http://rubygems.org/gems/aes),

```
@key="f6c57ea9f82731d3e125b4d2618423c0" #(it is 32 long, but i wonder how many bit it is in php?)
@message="123;456"
@str=AES.encrypt(@message,@key)
  #=>"sGvYXk3LhU30xge4rKcYYA==$yypKQjUvUF95YoiVfdbyPA==" ##init_vector and cipher_text are joined with "$"
```

I pass `@str` to a php file, but it just can't decrypt it, it all mess up in php. And why the `@str` is
different at each encryption with the same message and key?

## php

```
$str="yypKQjUvUF95YoiVfdbyPA==";
$iv_dec="sGvYXk3LhU30xge4rKcYYA==";
$key="f6c57ea9f82731d3e125b4d2618423c0";
$message=mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key,
                                $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);

##Puts out:  PHP Warning:  mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) 3 things wrong with the PHP code:

1. You are using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` which is not AES, `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` is AES;
2. You need to decode the key from the hexadecimal value (so it is actually 16 *bytes* long, therefor AES-128 is being used);
3. You need to base 64 decode the IV and ciphertext.

Comment: It still not work. `$cipher= base64_decode($iv_dec); $key2=hextobin($key);  $str2=base64_decode($str); $message=mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key2,
                                $str2, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $cipher);  $mes= base64_encode($message);  echo $mes; ` It can echo something(`wufrx1tYHg5hVtwFdz70nw==`) but not the same as the original message(`hello;world`). Is there also a require for the length of the message to be encrypted? If it dose not meet the need, then it automatically padding it?